# Spring boot - Unsupported config data location 'optional:file:./config/*/'

Tags: spring-boot, classloader, java-11, tomcat9, urlclassloader

We are migrating a spring boot application from 2.2.4 to 2.4.3

 The application can be run with inbuilt tomcat / Tomcat war deployment.

 **Environment**: Windows Azul Java 11 (Zulu 11) and Tomcat 9.0.33

If I run the code with my Netbeans linked tomcat, it works fine.

If I deploy the generated war directly in the same standalone tomcat, it throws the following error.

```
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.33-without port - rest.war]
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
................................................................
................................................................
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.config.UnsupportedConfigDataLocationException: Unsupported config data location 'optional:file:./config/*/'
                at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:110)
```

On reading through the Spring document, it was mentioned that By default, Spring Boot includes config/*/ in the default search locations. Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-files-wildcards

I further debugged with spring boot source and spring core source and identified that there is a mismatch in the classloader that happens that was the cause of this exception.

SpringFactoriesLoader is the class that gets loaded by **ParallelWebAppClassLoader** in NB linked tomcat and by **URLClassLoader** in standalone tomcat.

Ref: Line No 129 at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/io/support/SpringFactoriesLoader.java#L129

The cache at Line 136 has the config classes loaded by ParallelWebAppClassLoader, but not by the URLlassLoader. So the 2 resolvers - ConfigTreeConfigDataLocationResolver, StandardConfigDataLocationResolver in boot v2.4.3 are not getting identified when it tries to retrieve with the key URLlassLoader (Line 136).

Not sure whether this is an issue with Springboot / SpringCore / Tomcat / any new configuration to be added as a part of our upgrade.

 Note: Our application.properties has spring.servlet.multipart related properties only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue in Spring boot.
Updating to version 2.4.6 will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

"./" is not getting resolved in standalone tomcat.

Try using classpath:application.properties , or classpath:config/* -- this would require props inside war.

or absolute path of file:/var/myapp/config/*.   Since tomcat is in D:, you may create a folder d:/var/myapp/config/.

Note that within spring you can ignore "d:" and just mention  "/var/myapp/config/*", so, in-case tomcat is in "x:" your code need not change.

Comment: As I have already mentioned, I didn't add any config such as ./config/*/. Its added automatically by Springboot. I don't have any specific config for my application.